# DOMDocument foreach replacement

Tags: php, domdocument

In the foreach loop below, what is the proper syntax in order to return only the first instance of the keyword, wrapping it in bold tags, then exiting the loop and function?

For example, the keyword is "blue widgets". So I want the first appearance of the string (in $content) to be changed from blue widgets to

```
<b>blue widgets</b>
```

Here's the routine I'm using to parse the content...

```
function sx_decorate_keyword($content){
    $keyword = "blue widgets";
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadHTML($content);
    $x = new DOMXpath($d);
    foreach($x->query("//text()[
       contains(.,$keyword')
       and not(ancestor::h1) 
       and not(ancestor::h2) 
       and not(ancestor::h3) 
       and not(ancestor::h4) 
       and not(ancestor::h5) 
       and not(ancestor::h6)]") as $node){
        //need to wrap bold tags around the first instance of the keyword, then exit the routine
    }  
return $content;
}
```

Comment: Just curios, why not just use preg_replace?

Comment: @Dmitri - not partial to either.

Comment: @Dmitri: can you perhaps give provide an example using preg_replace with the "not in a heading tag" exception?

Answer (score 2):

As Dmitri mentioned, just work on the first text node only.  The example below takes the approach of dissecting the DOMText node containing your keyword(s) and wrapping the first occurrence within a `<b>` element.

```
$nodes = $x->query("... your xpath ...");
if ($nodes && $nodes->length) {
    $node = $nodes->item(0);
    // Split just before the keyword
    $keynode = $node->splitText(strpos($node->textContent, $keyword));
    // Split after the keyword
    $node->nextSibling->splitText(strlen($keyword));
    // Replace keyword with <b>keyword</b>
    $replacement = $d->createElement('b', $keynode->textContent);
    $keynode->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $keynode);
}
```

Reference:

- [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/domnodelist) - The result from `DOMXPath::query()`
- [`DOMText::splitText()`](http://php.net/domtext.splittext) - Breaks this node into two nodes at the specified offset
- [`DOMNode::replaceChild()`](http://php.net/domnode.replacechild) - Replaces a child

Answer (score 0):

You can just break out of the loop using the **break;**

Or you can not use foreach and instead just work on the first element only.

```
    $Matches = $x->query("//text()[
           contains(.,$keyword')
           and not(ancestor::h1) 
           and not(ancestor::h2) 
           and not(ancestor::h3) 
           and not(ancestor::h4) 
           and not(ancestor::h5) 
           and not(ancestor::h6)]");

if($Matches && $Matches->length > 0){
  $myText = $Matches->item(0);
  // now do you thing with $myText like create <b> element, append $myText as child,
  // replaceNode $myText with new <b> node
}
```

Not sure if this will work, but something like that...